# How can I pass a value to Django Form's init method from a view?

Tags: django, forms, view, init, choicefield

forms.py

```
class AddDuration(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(AddDuration, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        // set value to relates_to_choices
        relates_to_choices = ????????????? // Something like self.choices
        self.fields['duration'].choices = relates_to_choices

    duration = forms.ChoiceField(required=True)
```

Now, I have a views.py file that has a class

```
class AddDurationView(FormView):
    template_name = 'physician/add_duration.html'
    form_class = AddDurationForm
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override the [`get_form_kwargs()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/views/generic/edit.py#L47-L61) method on the view.

`views.py`

```
class AddDurationView(FormView):
    template_name = 'physician/add_duration.html'
    form_class = AddDurationForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AddDurationView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['duration_choices'] = (
            ('key1', 'display value 1'),
            ('key2', 'display value 2'),
        )
        return kwargs
```

`forms.py`

```
class AddDurationForm(forms.Form):
    duration = forms.ChoiceField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, duration_choices, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(AddDurationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        // set value to duration_choices
        self.fields['duration'].choices = duration_choices
```